# Como usar top no estilo de imagens com largura relativa?

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            img {position: absolute; height: auto; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 100%; position: absolute; top:0px; left:0px;">
            <img style="width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;" src="dad.png" />
            <img style="width: 28%; top: 3%; left: 38%;" src="img1.png" />
            <img style="width: 28%; top: 29%; left: 38%;" src="img2.png" />
            <img style="width: 28%; top: 55%; left: 38%;" src="img3.png" />
            <img style="width: 28%; top: 3%; left: 69%;" src="img4.png" />
            <img style="width: 28%; top: 29%; left: 69%;" src="img5.png" />
            <img style="width: 28%; top: 55%; left: 69%;" src="img6.png" />

            <!-- Mais código vai ser adicionado à DIV -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aqui tenho uma imagem "maior" na origem do documento e "sobre" essa imagem posiciono outras 6 imagens menores. Porém a imagem maior deve ter a mesma largura da browser (relativo), e não perder a proporção, logo: altura desconhecida (automática).

**Problema:** pelo fato de a altura ser desconhecida; e ser impossível aninhar as imagens, a propriedade `top` relativa (%) não é aplicada às outras imagens.

**Observação:** a propriedade `left` relativa (%) funciona normalmente pois o tamanho da `div`pai é reconhecido.

Alguém sabe de alguma forma para realizar esse posicionamento tão relativo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que tudo tem posição absoluta. Nesse caso, a altura das imagens não influencia na altura da div externa. Portanto a div externa tem altura zero, e qualquer porcentagem de zero também é zero.

Sugiro deixar a imagem maior sem `position: absolute`, e aplicar isso só nas outras, usando uma classe (`child`, no exemplo abaixo):

```css
img.child {position: absolute; }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; position: relative; top:0px; left:0px;">
    <img style="width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;" src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg">
    <img class="child" style="width: 28%; top: 3%; left: 38%;" src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg">
    <img class="child" style="width: 28%; top: 29%; left: 38%;" src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg">
    <img class="child" style="width: 28%; top: 55%; left: 38%;" src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg">
    <img class="child" style="width: 28%; top: 3%; left: 69%;" src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg">
    <img class="child" style="width: 28%; top: 29%; left: 69%;" src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg">
    <img class="child" style="width: 28%; top: 55%; left: 69%;" src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Adicione um `position: relative` no estilo da `div` do contrário não funciona. Pelo menos não funcionou aqui.

Comment: Como assim? Eu mantive o position: absolute do seu exemplo e funcionou (clique "executar trecho de código" acima).

Comment: Tente por mais conteúdo na página.